# Бэкграунд из квадратных точек

Tags: css, css3, html5, svg, css-animation

Я хочу получить бэкграунд, как в моем [примере](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/jjBwep), только с прозрачным фоном (а не белым).

Это возможно на CSS без изображений?

```
  body {
      background: linear-gradient(90deg, #fff 20px, transparent 1%) center, linear-gradient(#fff 20px, transparent 1%) center, #000;
      background-size: 22px 22px;
     }
```

Comment: Задний фон страницы не может быть прозрачным, так как за ним ничего не расположено.

Comment: @StrangerintheQ в реальной жизни у меня боди с изображением, а поверх него див с бэкграундом в виде точек. Хочу добиться того, чтобы через него было видно изображение. У меня получилось реализовать такое с помощью круглых точек, но квадратные я не знаю как сделать. Ниже поделились интересным решением через .svg, но у него есть небольшой недостаток, ему нельзя задать background-repeat: space, чтобы заполнение точками было равномерным

P.S.: не то чтобы я не любил круглые точки, но они криво рендерятся в браузерах <2014-2015

Comment: @Jenya , `background-repeat: space` работает, если задать высоту для `body`. У этого тега есть своя специфика в заполнении фоном

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Использование pattern SVG

Фон растровая картинка, а поверх неё будет сетка из квадратных точек, которые реализованы с помощью `pattarn` Более подробно о паттернах [здесь](https://svg-art.ru/?page_id=875)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
<pattern id="ptn1"
   x="0" y="0" width="22" height="22"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >

            <g fill="#85D2FF"  fill-opacity="0.9">
             <rect x="0" y="0" width="2" height="2" />
            </g>
  </pattern>
```

Цифры на рисунке немного другие, как в коде, но суть не меняется

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1400 875" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
 <pattern id="ptn1"
   x="0" y="0" width="22" height="22"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
               
            <g fill="#85D2FF"  fill-opacity="0.9">
              <rect x="0" y="0" width="2" height="2" />
            </g> 
  </pattern>    
</defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/K37YC.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#ptn1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

**Можно сделать варианты анимаций паттерна**

Точки увеличиваются в размере и перекрывают картинку

```
<rect x="0" y="0" width="2" height="2" >
 <animate attributeName="width" values="2;22;22;2;2" begin="svg1.click" dur="6s"/>
    <animate attributeName="height" values="2;22;22;2;2" begin="svg1.click" dur="6s"/>
</rect>
```

**анимация после клика**

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1400 875" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
 <pattern id="ptn1"
   x="0" y="0" width="22" height="22"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
               
            <g fill="skyblue"  fill-opacity="0.8">
             <rect x="0" y="0" width="2" height="2" >
    <animate attributeName="width" values="2;22;22;2;2" begin="svg1.click" dur="6s"/>
      <animate attributeName="height" values="2;22;22;2;2" begin="svg1.click" dur="6s"/>
    </rect>
     
 </pattern>   
</defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/K37YC.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#ptn1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

**Горизонтальные жалюзи**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1400 875" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
 <pattern id="ptn1"
   x="0" y="0" width="11" height="22"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
               
    <g fill="skyblue"  fill-opacity="0.8">
             <rect x="0" y="0" width="2" height="2" >
    <animate attributeName="width" values="2;22;22;2;2" begin="svg1.click" dur="6s"/>
      <animate attributeName="height" values="2;22;22;2;2" begin="svg1.click" dur="6s"/>
    </rect>
 </g>    
 </pattern>   
</defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/K37YC.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#ptn1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

**Вертикальные жалюзи**

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```html
<style>
.container {
width:100%;
height:100%;
}
</style>
<div class="container">
<svg id="svg1" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
       width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1400 875" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet">  
<defs>
 <pattern id="ptn1"
   x="0" y="0" width="22" height="11"
             patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse" >
           <g fill="skyblue"  fill-opacity="0.8">
             <rect x="0" y="0" width="2" height="2" >
    <animate attributeName="width" values="2;22;22;2;2" begin="svg1.click" dur="6s"/>
      <animate attributeName="height" values="2;22;22;2;2" begin="svg1.click" dur="6s"/>
    </rect> 
   </g> 
     
 </pattern>   
</defs>
<image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/K37YC.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"  /> 
<rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="url(#ptn1)" />
</svg>  
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Не то чтобы совсем без изображений. Без внешних изображений.

```css
body{
  background-image: url('data:image/svg+xml;utf8,<svg width="22" height="22" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><rect width="2" height="2" /></svg>');
  background-size: 22px 22px;
  background-color:#cda;
}
```

Comment: Геннадий не хотел у тебя отбирать галочку, по себе знаю, как это неприятно бывает. Я компенсирую, у тебя почти всегда хорошие ответы

Comment: Нет! Моя галочка!

Comment: @Alexandr_TT , а если серьёзно - переживания из-за рейтинга, галочек и пр.  это как-то странно. Сам я сижу на SO не для того, чтобы в получить доступ к его статистике. Например из этого вопроса узнал, что у свойства `background-repeat` есть значения `space` и `round`. Т.е. принцип "помогая другим, учишься сам" реально работает.

Comment: люди все разные, некоторых всерьез захватывает эта виртуальная игра, хотя конечно я понимаю, что есть ресурс SO, есть рейтинг, нет ресурса, нет рейтинга. Остаются только знания. Но с другой стороны, я всегда поддерживаю людей с хорошими ответами, потому что, как это не странно, отсутствие внимания к хорошим ответам, отбивает желание делиться своими знаниями

Answer (score 0):

CSS вариант:

```css
div { 
  background: 
    radial-gradient(circle at 0px 0px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 1px 0px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 2px 0px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 3px 0px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 0px 1px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 1px 1px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 2px 1px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 3px 1px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 0px 2px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 1px 2px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 2px 2px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 3px 2px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 0px 3px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 1px 3px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 2px 3px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px),
    radial-gradient(circle at 3px 3px, #000 0.5px, #0000 1px)
    ;
  background-size: 20px 20px;
  height: 100vh;
}

body {
  background: wheat;
}
```

```html
<div/>
```