# Z-индекс изображения при наведении на несколько SVG полигонов

Tags: html, css, svg, css-animation

Я работаю над SVG, моя концепция состоит в том, что у меня есть два изображения, которые пересекаются друг с другом, и используя многоугольник SVG, я сделал пять разных треугольников.

Моя цель - добиться первого наложения части фигуры от полного отображения изображения  при наведении курсора на фон фигуры.  Границы  многоугольника также должны быть видны.

Это мой исходный код перед наложением изображения:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
}

polygon {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: red;
  fill: #ffffff;
}

polygon:hover {
  fill: transparent;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <svg viewbox="0 0 200 100">
  <polygon points="0,100 100,100 0,50 "
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="0,50 100,100 50,00 0,0 "
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 50,00 150,0"
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 200,50 200,0 150,0"
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 200,100, 200,50"
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Теперь я добавил `overlay` изображение, которое должно располагаться над изображением `.box` и многоугольниками. Теперь, при наведении курсора, я хочу отобразить .box изображение в текущей форме многоугольника, как это

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

код здесь:

```css
.box {
  position: relative;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
}

polygon {
  stroke-width: 1;
  stroke: red;
  fill: #ffffff;
}

polygon:hover {
  fill: transparent;
}

.overlay:hover polygon {
  z-index: 100;
}

.overlay {
  position: absolute;
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 100%;
  height: 600px;
  background-size: cover;
  z-index: 10;
}
```

```html
<div class="overlay"></div>
<div class="box">

  <svg viewbox="0 0 200 100">
  <polygon points="0,100 100,100 0,50 "
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="0,50 100,100 50,00 0,0 "
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 50,00 150,0"
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 200,50 200,0 150,0"
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
  <polygon points="100,100 200,100, 200,50"
       style="stroke:#000000;"/>
 </svg>
</div>
```

Может ли кто-нибудь помочь мне с этим при наведении курсора. Нужно отрегулировать z-индексы div и заполнения полигонов.

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/56574418/7394871

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
rect, polygon {
  stroke-width: 0;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

rect, polygon:hover {
  fill: url(#f);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 200">
  <pattern id="f" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" />
  </pattern>
  <rect x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" />
  <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
  <polygon points="0,100 100,100 0,50" />
  <polygon points="0,50 100,100 50,00 0,0" />
  <polygon points="100,100 50,00 150,0" />
  <polygon points="100,100 200,50 200,0 150,0" />
  <polygon points="100,100 200,100, 200,50" />
</svg>
```

Если нижняя часть изображения не нужна, то так:

```css
svg {
  overflow: hidden;
}

polygon {
  stroke-width: 0;
  stroke: transparent;
  fill: none;
  pointer-events: all;
}

polygon:hover {
  fill: url(#f);
}
```

```html
<svg viewbox="0 0 200 100">
  <pattern id="f" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
    <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="200" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMin slice" />
  </pattern>
  <image xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice" />
  <polygon points="0,100 100,100 0,50" />
  <polygon points="0,50 100,100 50,00 0,0" />
  <polygon points="100,100 50,00 150,0" />
  <polygon points="100,100 200,50 200,0 150,0" />
  <polygon points="100,100 200,100, 200,50" />
</svg>
```

Comment: ваше решение SVG более лаконично, чем решение от `@Kaiido`, но смотрится хуже, чем у него, из-за черных рамок полигонов и необрезанного изображения внизу при полноэкранном просмотре

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, рамки убрал, а то я думал, что они нужны. А вот про необрезанное изображение вообще не понял.

Comment: открой в полноэкранном режиме переводные ответ `@Kaiido` и свой ответ и увидишь, что низ картинки до полигонов у него спрятан

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, погоди. В коде в вопросе нижняя часть есть, я её сделал. При этом ни в одном из ответов её нет. Я вот не понимаю, она нужна или нет??

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, дополнил ответ.

Comment: ♦ отлично! Решение и плюсик я уже раньше поставил, так что спасибо за оперативность и новое решение

Comment: такое кстати можно запилить без svg, через transform skew

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, вот через border представляю (но это не точно), а через transform что-то нет... Не хочешь показать?

Comment: @Qwertiy ок, попозже, я вчера начал пилить ответ, но там получалась огромная пачка css и передумал

Comment: @StrangerintheQ, хотя вот так можно: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/676530/178988

Comment: @Qwertiy ну да, как-то так, только я делал через skew

Answer (score 5):

Я  скорректировал код [моего предыдущего ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56562302/8620333), как показано ниже:

```css
.box {
  width:450px;
  height:250px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:0;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/13/1000/800) center/cover;
}
.box > div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  opacity:0;
}
.box > div:nth-child(1) {
  clip-path:polygon(20% 0,80% 0, 50% 100%);
}
.box > div:nth-child(2) {
  clip-path:polygon(0 0, 20% 0,50% 100%,0 40%);
}
.box > div:nth-child(3) {
  clip-path:polygon(100% 0,80% 0,50% 100%,100% 40%);
}

.box > div:nth-child(4) {
  clip-path:polygon(0 100%,50% 100%,0 40%);
}
.box > div:nth-child(5) {
  clip-path:polygon(100% 100%,50% 100%,100% 40%);
}

.box > div:hover {
   opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/10/1000/800)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/90/1000/800)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/102/1000/800)"></div>
  <div style="background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800)"></div>
</div>
```

Вот иллюстрация, чтобы показать вам различные точки, используемые в пути клипа

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

С тем же изображением? как у автора:

```css
.box {
  width:450px;
  height:250px;
  position:relative;
  overflow:hidden;
  z-index:0;
  background:url(https://picsum.photos/id/13/1000/800) center/cover;
}
.box > div {
  position:absolute;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  background-image:url(https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800);
  background-size:cover;
  background-position:center;
  opacity:0;
}
.box > div:nth-child(1) {
  clip-path:polygon(20% 0,80% 0, 50% 100%);
}
.box > div:nth-child(2) {
  clip-path:polygon(0 0, 20% 0,50% 100%,0 40%);
}
.box > div:nth-child(3) {
  clip-path:polygon(100% 0,80% 0,50% 100%,100% 40%);
}

.box > div:nth-child(4) {
  clip-path:polygon(0 100%,50% 100%,0 40%);
}
.box > div:nth-child(5) {
  clip-path:polygon(100% 100%,50% 100%,100% 40%);
}

.box > div:hover {
   opacity:1;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <div ></div>
  <div ></div>
  <div ></div>
  <div ></div>
  <div ></div>
</div>
```

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56576696/7394871): @Temani Afif

Comment: Кстати, clip-path можно анимировать)))

Comment: @Qwertiy этим svg и отличается от CSS, что позволяет анимировать практически любую и формулу и её атрибуты Пример [из недавнего ответа по паттернам](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/995494/28748)

Comment: Я имел в виду, что css'ный clip-path можно анимировать.

Answer (score 4):

[Решение @Temani Afif только на CSS очень хорошее](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56576696/3702797)

Однако, будьте осторожны, это все еще [не поддерживается ни в Safari, ни в IE / Edge](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clip-path#Browser_compatibility).

Для этих браузеров вам понадобится использовать SVG, который также реализует элемент `<clipPath>`.

```css
.overlay {
  background-image: url('https://picsum.photos/id/118/1000/800');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
.overlay use {
  opacity: 0;
}
.overlay use:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<svg class="overlay" viewBox="0 0 200 100">
  <defs>
    <clipPath id='clip-1'>
      <polygon points="0,100 100,100 0,50"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-2'>
      <polygon points="0,50 100,100 50,00 0,0"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-3'>
      <polygon points="100,100 50,00 150,0"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-4'>
      <polygon points="100,100 200,50 200,0 150,0"/>
    </clipPath>
    <clipPath id='clip-5'>
      <polygon points="100,100 200,100, 200,50"/>
    </clipPath>
    <image id="img" x="0" y="0" width="200" height="100" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid slice"
      xlink:href="https://picsum.photos/id/1/1000/800" />
  </defs>
  <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-1)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-2)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-3)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-4)"/>
  <use xlink:href="#img" clip-path="url(#clip-5)"/>
</svg>
<div class="box"></div>
```

**Так что,  это более многострочно в коде, но это должно работать в любом браузере начиная с IE9.**

[Источник ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56590601/7394871): @Kaiido